# What add_action reference should I be using or should I use do_action?

Tags: functions, actions, email

I am working on some automated emails.    I am fairly new to add_action and do_action.  I am having a tough time understanding it.  The site in question has number goals set up that people reach  over time.  I want to send them an email when they hit the goal.  The code below will send that email when the post is updated but that won't work.  I put it there just to make sure the email sends out.  I don't know what add_action I should use.  What reference should I be looking for to do this?

```
function emailNotificationSuccess($post_id) {

  if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $goalsupport === $totalsupport ) ) {

   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
   $totalsupport = countSupportForAll($post->ID);
   $goalsupport = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sj_campaign_goal', true );
   $supporter_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sj_campaign_email', true );
   $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.",


Congrats! You have reached your goal!

Your , ".$post->post_title." is a success!

".get_permalink( $post_id )."


   ";
   wp_mail($supporter_email, "You just reached your goal!", $message);

  } 
} 
add_action('post_updated', 'emailNotificationSuccess');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the conditional, not with the used action (I think).

This line is probably not verifying in any situation:

```
if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $goalsupport === $totalsupport ) ) {
```

I can not now what $goalsupport and $goalsupport are, both variables are undefined in your code, so I'm going to remove them. Change that line with this one:

```
if( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' ) {
```

So, the code should be:

```
function emailNotificationSuccess($post_id) {

  if( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' ) {

   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
   $totalsupport = countSupportForAll($post->ID);
   $goalsupport = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sj_campaign_goal', true );
   $supporter_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sj_campaign_email', true );
   $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.",


Congrats! You have reached your goal!

Your , ".$post->post_title." is a success!

".get_permalink( $post_id )."


   ";
   wp_mail($supporter_email, "You just reached your goal!", $message);

  } 
} 
add_action('post_updated', 'emailNotificationSuccess');
```

Comment: If I take those out then there is no way to tell when it has hit its goal.

Comment: As I said in the answer, `$goalsupport` and `$totalsupport` are undefined variables in your code, so you can not check them; that is why I removed them, there is nothing to check anyway. Try to **publish** a post with my code and you will see. Then try to build your "goal" checking.